# How to deserialize json string in windows phone?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

I just got my json response as a string.My  json is given below,

```
"code": 0,
"message": "success",
"students": {
   "details":{
    "hjeke": {
        "id": "257633000000070001",
        "name": "hjeke",
        "percentage": 36,
        "type": "Good",
    },
    "Second": {
        "id": "257633000000073001",
        "name": "Second",
        "percentage": 4,
        "type": "bad",
    }
  }
}
```

Like *hjeke* and *Second* there are many key value pairs,how can i deserialize my json using **Newtonsoft.json**

Comment: Better solution example.
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/9681048/1337636

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to understand my solution in your previous question
[How to deserialize json data in windows phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783272/how-to-deserialize-json-data-in-windows-phone/19785311#19785311)

Your first JSON in that question was good and simple to use. 
JSON, where field names are unique not convinient to deserialize. So, you got problems such as `public class Hjeke` and `public class Second` for each instance, when you use code generator.

Use JSON-structure with list of students:

```
"code": 0,
"message": "success",
"students": [
    {
        "id": "257633000000070001",
        "name": "hjeke",
        "percentage": 36,
        "type": "Good",
    },
    {
        "id": "257633000000073001",
        "name": "Second",
        "percentage": 4,
        "type": "bad",
    }]
```

is good and flexible structure. Using this, you don't need to parse not obvious fields like

```
"details":{
    "hjeke": {
```

and so on.

And work with them using classes, from my previous answer. The main idea - you need list of objects. `public List<StudentDetails> students`. Then, all `students` objects deserialized in List, which is easy to use.

Comment: i dont have control over json! so what shall i do?

Comment: I thought, it's your choice to use this structure, sorry. Try to use  solution by Anton Sizikov below, it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

As everybody mentioned your json seems to be very unflexible, huh.

You can extract the data you are interested in.

So this is your model:

```
public class StudentDetails
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int percentage { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how you can extract it:

```
        var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(str);
        // get JSON result objects into a list
        var results = jsonObj["students"]["details"].Children().Values();

        // serialize JSON results into .NET objects
        var details = new List<StudentDetails>();
        foreach (JToken result in results) 
        {
            var st = result.ToString();
            var searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StudentDetails>(st);
            details.Add(searchResult);
        }
```

I'm using a newtonsoft.json library here.

Answer (score 1):

Your Response string has some mistakes man, its not a valid json

just small modification to be done as below:

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "success",
    "students": {
        "details": {
            "hjeke": {
                "id": "257633000000070001",
                "name": "hjeke",
                "percentage": 36,
                "type": "Good"
            },
            "Second": {
                "id": "257633000000073001",
                "name": "Second",
                "percentage": 4,
                "type": "bad"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can make out the difference

Now Follow these steps:

**1**.Go to this link [Json to C#](http://json2csharp.com/)

**2**.place your Json string there and generate C# class object

**3**.Now create this class in your solution

**4**.Now deserialize As below

```
var DeserialisedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Your Class>(YourJsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create the classes:

```
public class Hjeke
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int percentage { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Second
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int percentage { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Details
{
    public List<Hjeke> hjeke { get; set; }
    public List<Second> Second { get; set; }
}

public class Students
{
    public List<Details> details { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<Students> students { get; set; }
}
```

After that, use JSON.NET to deserialize:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(YourStringHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any influence over the json response? Details should probably be a JSONArray in this case, not an object with a varying amount of properties, since I assume that's what you mean is the issue here.