# Extract key from JSON String

Tags: c#, json, cordova

I use Apache Cordova in my Windows Phone application, and i need to get string values in a JSON Object.

How can i get the json key "version" for example ?

I try to do this but without results ..

```
public void dispatcherEvent(string result)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("EVENT received = " +result);

     try
     {
         string optVal = JsonHelper.Deserialize<string[]>(result)[0];
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
          // simply catch the exception, we will handle null values and exceptions together
     }

}
```

Actually, output console is :

```
EVENT received = ["{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"onConnectResult\",\"data\":\"[{\\\"version\\\":\\\"2.0.000.000\\\"}]\"}","ap246039464"]
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680631/json-deserializing-for-windows-phone

Answer (score 1):

Take a look and [Newtonsoft's JSON library](http://james.newtonking.com/json). With it you can do stuff like:

```
 string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
// Bad Boys
```

It is also available in [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

Comment: i copied it from the example on the main page :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a JsonModel. I use this in a project of me like this:

```
public class JsonModel
{
    [JsonProperty("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` to get a strong typed instance of your model.

```
JsonModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(result);
string version = model.Version;
```